# jQuery not loading on wp single post pages

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I've created a Genesis child theme which on the whole is working fine apart from that on single posts wp_footer() isn't loading jQuery so I get "Reference Error: jQuery not defined".

On every other page the following loads:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://domainname.com/wp-includes/js/wp-embed.min.js?ver=4.4.2'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://domainname.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.11.3'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://domainname.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery-migrate.min.js?ver=1.2.1'></script>
```

But on single blog posts this is what's loaded:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://domainname.com/wp-includes/js/comment-reply.min.js?ver=4.4.2'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://domainname.com/wp-includes/js/wp-embed.min.js?ver=4.4.2'></script>
```

Does anyone know why this is happening or how to stop it?

Comment: where are you loading jQuery in header or footer?

Comment: by default genesis is loadiing it in the footer. I had considered using if ( is_page_template('single.php') to manually call jquery but I'd rather fix the problem than create a work around

Answer (score 0):

Check if your footer.php is being called or not. 
And please post your how have you en queued your j query

Comment: Hi, footer.php is certainly being called. The truth is I dont know how jQuery is being enqueued, it's just however genesis is set up out of the box. It's the first time I've worked with the genesis theme.

Comment: hello! it is possible that there is a mistake in the dependency declaration. (Wordpress by default runs the lates jQuery for your infromation.) I am guessing there is a problem in enqueue while passing the dependency. 
Please check it. 
The enqueue is on the function.php file 
could you paste the code here ?